# What kind of snapshot isolation does StackOverflow use?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I read [Jeff Atwood's article on Sql Server deadlocks](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/deadlocked.html).  He said he switched the isolation level to use snapshots. I've seen two types of snapshot commands. I'm wondering--what command(s) did he run?

Only Read_Committed_Snapshot?

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname>  SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Or only Allow_Snapshot_Isolation?

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname>  SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
```

Or Both?

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname>  SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
ALTER DATABASE <dbname>  SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Comment: If one is good, both is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like both are required. It is documented here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(VS.80).aspx

> Snapshot isolation must be enabled by setting the ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON database option before it is used in transactions. This activates the mechanism for storing row versions in the temporary database (tempdb).
>
> Setting the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON option allows access to versioned rows under the default READ COMMITTED isolation level. If the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option is set to OFF, you must explicitly set the Snapshot isolation level for each session in order to access versioned rows.

Comment: Jeff, both are not required.  `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` just makes snapshots the *default*; otherwise you explicitly have to `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT` before every `BEGIN TRAN` where you want that particular mode.

Comment: @aaro I still don't understand. what happens if you issue R_C_S ON without issuing A_S_I ON? In other words, we're turning on an option that.. isn't yet allowed?

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to turn RCS on without ASI.  But the other way around is acceptable.  You can use ASI with explicit snapshot transactions, and other transactions will simply use the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation (no snapshot).